# IMPORTXML shows "array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in the C4" error

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query, importxml

I am able to fetch data from multiple URL's listed in a single column in Google Sheets using IMPORTHTML/IMPORTXML formula. However, when I drag the column with the formula it overwrites the existing data of the previous results. The error that I get is:

> Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in the C4

Here is a [live example to test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eFrLYk9T7mNUGRRFpcP_dP0v6tptDZCPTzGdAe4RVlM/edit?usp=sharing).

**Sheet1** contains the formula and error I see. (cells - C3,C4,C5)

**Sheet2** is the desired output using IMPORTXML/IMPORTHTML formula.

How can obtain the desired result for 100+ URLs using a formula?

Answer (score 2):

When importing HTML you have to allow enough blank space (rows and columns) for the imported data. It seems you wish to import a table, so maybe 13 rows and 5 columns per cricketer. Move Sachin down to about Row20, Kumble down to about Row 40, and so on (you seem to have the spare columns needed).

If you want only say the matches played you could try [ARRAY_CONSTRAIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036) if to reduce the space between cricketers. If you want only say a single cell out of the table you could try [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242).

In Sheet2!A5 this:

```
=if(mod(row()-5,13)=0,offset(Sheet1!A$3,(row())/13,),"")
```

copied across to B5 and both copied down to suit may help to space the names and URLs apart appropriately. Then if you filter on ColumnA (excluding the merged cells) to select everything but blanks you should be able to copy down to suit the following in C5:

```
=IMPORTHTML(B5,"table",2)
```

Comment: I think you are on right track.

But it is little bit harder for me to understand. 

It would be great if you can make a changes to live sheet I've shared. (Its Editable :) )

Thanks